# How to ensure a Facebook application is installed by the user in Ruby on Rails 3.1.1 in Koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas, koala

I am using Koala gem and I want to ensure that the application is installed by the user. First, I try to validate the Facebook id from my database. It works for me, but it fails in one case if the user deletes the application from the user's Facebook account setting. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `graph.get_connections('me','permissions')`. There is already a field "installed".